# Itunes Connect: Can't See Build after processing

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

when i bullish my app , after uploading the app it takes much hours to finish processing , then the source that i uplaoded it disappear and at all the word " select a build before you submit your app " does not show and the cross sign does not show also

any help please thanks

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6waQs.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH9YQ.png]

Comment: The account in which you are uploading, a mail will be sent to that account regarding the issue. Check it you will find the reason why its happening.

Comment: Try with @RahulPatel comment +1

Answer (score 4):

Here are few things you should take care of :

- App may take few minutes, hours or even a day in processing. So first suggestion is to wait at least for 24 hour
- If still its not showing up the build than make sure you are using an updated Xcode version & application loader as per apple suggested. If not than update it & upload from the latest version
- While uploading  new build don't forget to change build number. You can keep version number as it is.
- Make sure the provisioning profile set up correctly & also in your iTunes account you have checked all terms & conditions. Nothing is pending.

Hope it will help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add In info.plist
2. And change build number. Than Resubmit again

If As this your problem not solved than check your email which apple give the reason

```
    Privacy - Camera Usage Description
    Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
```

[image]

Comment: how to add this in info.plist

Comment: Open your info.plist click. ClickPlus symbol than add this with some string value

Comment: Check my sreen shoot and add this. see these
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

Comment: i did that , but the same problem

Comment: I don't like that this is a stab in the dark. There's no way to know if this is the problem he's having, and throwing random shit into your info.plist is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your binary file is rejected by Apple, that's why it disappear after processing.

For finding what's the actual reason behind it, check mail box. This mail will send to that mail id which is used to login in iTunes connect.

Comment: Not always an email is sent.

Answer (score 1):

Your application will be disappear after the processing time if you miss something specially in info.plist.

iTunes will send you Email regarding the error.

if you wrote your program in another language, say Qt, you need to create image xcassets for your iOS application .

So, You need to Click on application name on XCode ->General -> App Icons and Launch Images-> App ICons Sources

Click on Use Assest Catalog and Migrate.
You need to drag all your images in icons folder of your project in image.xcassest folder.

Change the build Version on Identity tab in General
Save your project
Clean the project
Build it Once again
Click on Product -> Archive

Wait for some time to upload your application on iTunes, if the upload is successful, after processing your application, you will get a confirmation Email which says that your applicaiton is ready for testflight.